# How to callback plugin thread on Safari 5.1 on OSX?

Tags: javascript, plugins, browser, safari, npapi

The Gecko functions NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall / pluginthreadasynccall are not working for me on Safari 5.1 (Firefox works) - my function does not get called. I'm trying to make a function call back to JavaScript after performing a long-running task on another thread. How can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, we had the same problem with Safari 5.1 in [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) (which you should definitely look at if you're not familiar with it); NPN_PluginThreadAsyncCall no longer works. You haven't specified which platform you're on, so I'll show you what we use on both Mac and Windows.

On windows, we create a message HWND and we post a message to that HWND passing a void* in the event data as the LPARAM; the void* is converted back to a pointer to a data structure holding the params that pluginthreadasynccall would normally take, the call is made, and the data structure is freed.  The [message window class we use is here](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginCore/Win/WinMessageWindow.cpp), and [here is where the call is made](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/ActiveXCore/ActiveXBrowserHost.cpp#L47). (Note that we use the same mechanism for cross-thread calls in IE)

On Mac, we basically just use the objective-c performSelectorOnMainThread; we wrapped it into a class to make it easier to use from c++. The [scheduler class we use is here](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/PluginCore/Mac/OneShotManager.mm), and [here is where the call is made](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/src/NpapiCore/NpapiPluginModule_NPP.cpp#L134). Note that you need to be really careful because there are lots of possible race conditions with these and occasionally you end up with re-entrant code. FireBreath has dozens of hours of work put into perfecting the cross-thread calls; it's a deceptively tricky problem.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I ended up using performSelectorOnMainThread, which seems to work just fine :)